# How to hide an element when clicked outside of it?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to hide a button when I click outside an input box. I was able to use v-show and v-on:click to show the button when the input box is clicked. I installed v-click-outside but cant seem to figure it out! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code with expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Input will have a focus when you click it, so you can use `@blur` event on the input to achieve the same result as with click outside, and you don't even need to use external library.

You could also use `@focus` instead of `@click` on the input to display the button maybe. Depends on your needs.